# PHP RAND and fuzzy logic rules

Tags: php, fuzzy-logic

Well, let's say I have variable a, b and c:

```
a = R R R
b = S S S
c = T T T
number = 1 to 3;
```

In my case I need to display the 27 row of total (**var * var * var**), but the result need to be like this and generate random   number  between 1 to 3:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> R </td>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> S </td>
    <td> T </td>
    <td> number </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I achieve this result in php?

Any help will be very much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$a = ['R','R','R'];
$b = ['S','S','S'];
$c = ['T','T','T'];

$array = [$a, $b, $c];
<table>
for($i=0 ; i<27; i++) {
  <tr>
    <td> echo $array[rand(0,2)][rand(0,2)] ; </td>
    <td> echo $array[rand(0,2)][rand(0,2)] ; </td>
    <td> echo $array[rand(0,2)][rand(0,2)] ; </td>
    <td> echo rand(0,2)</td>
  </tr>
}
</table>
// !! you need to concat php with HTML !!
```

Comment: i have updated the answer, but still, you need to concat html with php

Comment: I get this error Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 on $c[rand(0, 2)][rand(0, 2)]; and yes, I've modified the code and concat html with php

Comment: Sorry, it should be `$array[rand(0, 2)][rand(0, 2)]`; not `$c`.. i have updated the answer